# In this Python 3 client-server example, client can't send more than one message

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, client-server

This is a simple client-server example where the server returns whatever the client sends, but reversed.

Server:

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
        print('RECEIVED: ' + str(self.data))
        self.request.sendall(str(self.data)[::-1].encode('utf-8'))

server = socketserver.TCPServer(('localhost', 9999), MyTCPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import threading

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',9999))

def readData():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data:
            print('Received: ' + data.decode('utf-8'))

t1 = threading.Thread(target=readData)
t1.start()

def sendData():
    while True:
        intxt = input()
        s.send(intxt.encode('utf-8'))

t2 = threading.Thread(target=sendData)
t2.start()
```

I took the server from an example I found on Google, but the client was written from scratch. The idea was having a client that can keep sending and receiving data from the server indefinitely.

Sending the first message with the client works. But when I try to send a second message, I get this error:

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host machine

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @vaultah: I'm not sure it's really a dup. The underlying problem is the same, but one of them is using low-level `socket` calls, and the other `TCPServer`, so the only way you'd know it's a dup is if you already knew how `TCPServer` worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `TCPServer`, the [`handle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.RequestHandler.handle) method of the handler gets called once to handle the entire session. This may not be entirely clear from the documentation, but `socketserver` is, like many libraries in the stdlib, meant to serve as clear sample code as well as to be used directly, which is why the docs link to [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/socketserver.py), where you can clearly see that it's only going to call `handle` once per connection ([`TCPServer.get_request`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/socketserver.py#l480) is defined as just calling `accept` on the socket).

So, your server receives one buffer, sends back a response, and then quits, closing the connection.

To fix this, you need to use a loop:

```
def handle(self):
    while True:
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
        if not self.data:
            print('DISCONNECTED')
            break
        print('RECEIVED: ' + str(self.data))
        self.request.sendall(str(self.data)[::-1].encode('utf-8'))
```

---

A few side notes:

First, using `BaseRequestHandler` on its own only allows you to handle one client connection at a time. As the [introduction in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) says:

> These four classes process requests *synchronously*; each request must be completed before the next request can be started. This isn’t suitable if each request takes a long time to complete, because it requires a lot of computation, or because it returns a lot of data which the client is slow to process. The solution is to create a separate process or thread to handle each request; the `ForkingMixIn` and `ThreadingMixIn` mix-in classes can be used to support asynchronous behaviour.

Those mixin classes are described further in the rest of the introduction, and [farther down the page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#server-creation-notes), and [at the bottom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins), with a nice example at the end. The docs don't make it clear, but if you need to do any CPU-intensive work in your handler, you want `ForkingMixIn`; if you need to share data between handlers, you want `ThreadingMixIn`; otherwise it doesn't matter much which you choose.

Note that if you're trying to handle a large number of simultaneous clients (more than a couple dozen), neither forking nor threading is really appropriate—which means `TCPServer` isn't really appropriate. For that case, you probably want [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), or a third-party library (Twisted, gevent, etc.).

---

Calling `str(self.data)` is a bad idea. You're just going to get the source-code-compatible representation of the byte string, like `b'spam\n'`. What you want is to *decode* the byte string into the equivalent Unicode string: `self.data.decode('utf8')`.

---

There's no guarantee that each `sendall` on one side will match up with a single `recv` on the other side. TCP is a stream of bytes, not a stream of messages; it's perfectly possible to get half a message in one `recv`, and two and a half messages in the next one. When testing with a single connection on localhost with the system under light load, it will probably appear to "work", but as soon as you try to deploy any code that assumes that each `recv` gets exactly one message, your code will break. See [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for more details. Note that if your messages are just lines of text (as they are in your example), using `StreamRequestHandler` and its `rfile` attribute, instead of `BaseRequestHandler` and its `request` attribute, solves this problem trivially.

---

You probably want to set `server.allow_reuse_address = True`. Otherwise, if you quit the server and re-launch it again too quickly, it'll fail with an error like `OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use`.

Comment: Is this server setup capable of accepting more than one client connection? If I understood it correctly, a new instance of the handler class is created for every new client. This solution worked for a single client, but it doesn't work when I try to connect a second client to the server.

Comment: @DavidMcDavidson: It can accept more than one client connection _consecutively_, but not more than one _simultaneously_. This is explained in detail in the introduction to the linked docs page, and a nice example of fixing it with the `ThreadingMixin` is at the very bottom of the same page.